# Returning an uploaded file's name

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5.3

Laravel automatically renames an uploaded file. How do I know (make it return) the uploaded file's new name? Is there any function that does this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try `storeAs()` function as:

```
$filename = 'filename.jpg';
$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', $filename);
retrun $filename;
```

From the docs

> If you do not want a file name to be automatically generated, you may use the `storeAs` method, which accepts the `path`, `file name`, and `disk name` as its arguments:

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#files)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But is there a way to still use the automatic method and get its name?